# Why do environment variables not override settings for AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService?

Tags: .net-core, appsettings

I have a web application (dotnetcore 6) running in a container in K8s and I call `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` and the environment variable for application insights overrides appsettings.json and it works fine.

I have a BackgroundService app (dotnetcore 6, IHostedService) running in a container in K8s and I call `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()` and the environment variables do not seem to override appsettings.json.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently have to do ...

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService (hostBuilderContext.Configuration);
```

... if you want the same behavior.

The newer `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()` method appears to not use `IConfiguration` by default and goes straight to appsettings.json.